# search query is not working mysql(wamp)

Tags: mysql

I never faced problem like this. I am using a simple search query in mysql (wamp)
my query is like this

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `m_email`='heena@gmail.com';
```

even not working if i am changing the values

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `m_email`='heena';
```

getting output like

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0012 sec )
```

but if I am tring to

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `m_id`=5 ;
//successful and showing output.

 see here the values in table in mysql(wamp)
Edit    Delete  5   heena   e7f4a1abdd69d6c9a5b3f8b8736ea2f3    956333652   0   female   


 here is the structure for m_email field
m_email     varchar(30)     latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

Comment: Please share sqlFiddle demo.

Comment: The corresponding password for that MD5 string is **"heena"** - I'd strongly recommend you to fix your password storage mechanism...

Comment: you have no such row with exactly 'heena@gmail.com' email value

Comment: blue i will fix that .. can you please tell me why a simple and basic query is not working here .

Comment: make sure there is no white space after/before the email value in db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/280684/aak that is because i was changing the value SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `m_email`='heena'; and wasnt working

Comment: Abhik Chakraborty  ya it was a 1 space .  and it is working now

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE trim(`m_email`)='heena@gmail.com';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE trim(`m_email`)='heena';
```

Comment: Are you kidding? it is only the middle query that might return something different and that is on the price of **NOT** using indexes ... Why would you want to give an advice like that?